# Preprocessor different function name same functionality

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a function defined as

```
int abc()
{
    // Some code here...
}
```

I need to integrate multiple projects which might have the same function name "abc()". I would like to have a preprocessor like

```
#if defined PREPROCESSOR1
    int A_abc()
#else
    int abc()
#endif
    {
        // Some code here...
    }
```

Is it possible to have something like a macro to replace this, instead of changing line by line in the code?

Comment: Is `a` an argument to function `abc()`?

Comment: Or is `a` a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```cc
#ifdef PREPROCESSOR1
#define ABC A_abc
#else
#define ABC abc
#endif

int ABC()
{
    // Some code here...
}
```

Comment: `a` is defined but never initialized. This code will print whatever garbage is sitting in memory where the space for `a` is allocated.

Comment: @Dogbert I don't think the body of the function is relevant here.

Comment: @aldo I disagree. The function declares a variable, and increments it, but never initializes it, meaning that all operations carried on it form one big set of undefined or unsafe behaviors. Also, since the variable `a` is defined within the function body, and is neither a global variable nor a function argument, it guarantees the result is undefined.

Comment: @Dogbert Who cares?  The OP should have left the body of the function empty (or used "...").  The question is about the naming of the function!

Comment: @aldo A lot of the exceptional editors on SO generally point out more than just the literal answer to the question. I find they often point out other issues, or post a comment for further clarification. Just providing a flippant, minimalist answer with no further insight is acceptable, but substandard IMHO. I think a number of editors would care.

Comment: The function definition should actually be `int A_abc()`, and `int abc()`.